# How to show difference in attribute for two different objects of two different classes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have two models, Article and EditedArticle, and both share an attribute called content. The attribute is currently being stored as text in the database.

If I have an instance of each Article and EditedArticle, a1 and ea1, and do the following:

```
unless a1.content == ea1.content
```

How could I highlight the differences in ea1.content when in the edited_articles#show view?
My guess is that I would have to do something with .each_line, but I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: [This](http://users.cybercity.dk/~dsl8950/ruby/diff.html) might helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the [diff library](http://users.cybercity.dk/~dsl8950/ruby/diff.html), which finds the differences between strings or arrays

also, you might find the [text gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/text) to be useful for this situation.

There's one more called [english](http://english.rubyforge.org/) that may help as well.